# Python - Getting A Page's Complete HTML Via Url / Request ERROR

Tags: python, html, url, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to get the html of this page:

```
 url = 'http://www.metacritic.com/movie/oslo-august-31st/critic-reviews'
```

and I'm trying to get it using requests:

```
 oslo = requests.get(url)
```

but they seem to know that I'm accessing it this way and when I open up 
the file I get:

```
\n\n\n403 Forbidden\n\n\nError 403 Forbidden\nForbidden\nGuru Meditation:\nXID: 961167012\n\nVarnish cache server\n\n\n
```

Is there any other way to access the html's other than manually copying and pasting every html from every page?

Comment: Some websites look at the "User Agent" header, or other headers, to tell if the request is coming from a web scraper.  Some websites will deny your request if they think you're a scraper.  What headers are you sending?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify a [`User-Agent` header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) to get 200 response:

```
import requests

url = 'http://www.metacritic.com/movie/oslo-august-31st/critic-reviews'

response = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36'})
print(response.status_code)
```